# Sending rsa keys over tcp

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, openssl, rsa

i'm trying to send a rsa key (RSA *myrsa) over tcp connection such way:

```
send(client, (char *)myrsa, sizeof(RSA), 0);
```

and recipient does:

```
read_bytes = tcpSocket.read(buffer, sizeof(RSA));
RSA *myrsa = RSA_new();
memcpy((void*)myrsa, (void*)buffer, read_bytes);
```

then RSA_check_key(rsa) returns -1 or crashes the programm.
What i do wrong? Maybe it exists more proper solution? Maybe the row message corrupts by any transformings?

Comment: 1) Why are you sending cryptographic material in the clear?
2) Is read_bytes the expected value?

Comment: @zmccord: The whole point of public key cryptography (or most of the point, anyway) is that it allows you to send a key in the clear without compromising security.

Comment: @zmccord: yes, read_bytes are expected to be 168 bytes;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -1 implies that there's an error in the data.  the RSA_check_keys method merely verifies that parameters are consistent, not that the data is necessarily valid.
Behaviour like a crash might also be consistent with bad data.

A couple of places where there might be issues:
Do you actually allocate room for buffer?
Do you check the length of read_bytes to make sure the data you received is likely an RSA key?